# vscode errors with tests

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

This week I noticed a problem when running tests in vs code.

Tests work correctly when run from the command-line, but VSCode itself at startup produces this error:

> Cannot read property '$' of undefined

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
Changing the version of the Python extension does not help

Comment: I forgot to add - I observe this problem only when using virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in package version. Repaired so **pip install pytest==5.0.1**
I don’t know what this may be connected with, but the problem in vs code disappeared